# Custom Styling Background Color for Mat-Menu in Angular Material

Tags: javascript, css, angular, less, angular-material

I am trying to override some Material2 styling in my Angular 2 app and so far I'm not able to get it to work. Specifically, I want to override the background color for the md-menu. This is what my html looks like:

```
<md-menu #menu="mdMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false" class="sub-drop-bg">
  <button md-menu-item routerLink="option-A" class="sub-drop-item">Option A</button>
...
</md-menu>
```

And this is what I've tried adding in my LESS/CSS:

```
md-menu.sub-drop-bg /deep/ {
  background-color: #555 !important;
}
```

So far this seems to have no effect. The default `#fff` background-color still shows up for the md-menu background.

As additional info, when I hover over and inspect element, I see the default `mat-menu-content` class as being styled with the white background, like this:

```
.mat-menu-content {
    background: #fff;
}
```

I've tried adding that class to my component CSS, and using it to override the background-color, also to no avail. If I "de-select" that color for that class in my browser console, the background color goes away (becomes transparent). But, as I say, adding that class and overriding the color in my CSS doesn't override the white color when I reload.

How can I accomplish this with CSS alone?

Comment: They have changed the css class from md-menu to mat-menu. In fact in material 2 beta 12 they have deprecated all md prefixes and it is now mat for all.

Comment: Right, but this is an Angular 2 app - as mentioned above.

Comment: As I can see from your tags within the html code, this is an Angular 2 app using Material. Execute "npm install @angular/material@latest" and you will get angular material 2 beta 12 installed. Had exactly the same problem as you.

Comment: md-menu and mat-menu are material tags and not pure angular tags.Look inside your package.json and you will find a reference to @angular/material

Comment: I get an error when trying to change that. Whereas md-menu works. So I will keep it that way until we upgrade to Angular 4.

Comment: There is a migration tool for changing all md tags to mat. Md has been deprecated in the newest version. You can get it at https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-material-prefix-updater

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not wrong, the following css should work for you:

```
/deep/ .mat-menu-content {
  background-color: #555 !important;
}
```

Comment: Tried it. No luck, unfortunately.

Comment: try: /deep/ .mat-menu-content { background: #555 !important; }

Comment: /deep/ is deprecated :(

Comment: Notice I said this in an Angular 2 app. /deep/ will work. ::ng-deep will not. But for Angular4 ::ng-deep would be the way to go.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use this:

```
::ng-deep .mat-menu-content{
  background-color:red;
}
```

[demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/KgXRaLR6nUn0HwS5Xsgk?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I read this article after an anomaly that I notice during my developing on angular 17 and cdk material last version at 17 febrary 2024.

Me too I cannot customize the background of mat-menu, unique tag with this problem, while others all tags work fine with my thematization impl.

All solutions that I read here don't work, but I gathering all clue and little delta information about this.

After an investigation on chrome inspection and analizying I notice that html declare set a variable on white color called --mat-menu-container-color by prebuild theme that in the my case is indigo-pink.scss

```
  html {
...
--mat-menu-container-color: white; //indigo-ping.scss value for this variable
...
 }
```

and there is the rule

```
      .mat-mdc-menu-panel {
        ...
        background-color: var(--mat-menu-container-color);
        ...
      }
```

that set the white by variable of the prebuild theme.

If I try all solutions that I read here dont work nothing ..but... but
if I reoverride all rulez into a ::ng-deep approach, all these styles and with a custom value, the background-color (on my example red just to test) work fine.

This is the test reoverride rule that I set on my specific component on specifico .scss style.

```
        ::ng-deep {
          .mat-mdc-menu-panel {
            ...
            background-color: var(--mat-menu-container-color);
            ...
           }
    
           html {
           ...
           --mat-menu-container-color: red; // this is my test 
           }
        }
```

Anyway there is a side effect that give a lot of hard critical thinking during to change a "simple" background color of a "simple" tag that show a menu (tag very crucial for a website).

I hate css and scss for this motivation, its a chaos ahah! So I hope that is usefull for others people.

for me this solution is a workaround, waiting a more straightforward approach to set these simple style by angular framework .

see u